# ChatMember TelegramBotApi in Java

Tags: java, telegram-bot

I try to check user of bot is member of given channel or group in telegram bot.

But I get an error
2024-03-13T10:09:20.136+05:00 ERROR 9440 --- [telegram-bot] [legram Executor] o.t.t.u.DefaultBotSession                : Error getting chat member: [400] Bad Request: user not found

org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException: Error getting chat member: [400] Bad Request: user not found
at org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.groupadministration.GetChatMember.deserializeResponse(GetChatMember.java:60) ~[telegrambots-meta-5.6.0.jar:na]
at org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.groupadministration.GetChatMember.deserializeResponse(GetChatMember.java:27) ~[telegrambots-meta-5.6.0.jar:na]
at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultAbsSender.sendApiMethod(DefaultAbsSender.java:1039) ~[telegrambots-5.6.0.jar:na]
at org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.bots.AbsSender.execute(AbsSender.java:64) ~[telegrambots-meta-5.6.0.jar:na]
at uz.elnuredu.telegrambot.telegrambot.service.TelegramBot.sendToNoneSubscribers(TelegramBot.java:147) ~[classes/:na]
at uz.elnuredu.telegrambot.telegrambot.service.TelegramBot.onUpdateReceived(TelegramBot.java:58) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596) ~[na:na]
at org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.generics.LongPollingBot.onUpdatesReceived(LongPollingBot.java:27) ~[telegrambots-meta-5.6.0.jar:na]
at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$HandlerThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:317) ~[telegrambots-5.6.0.jar:na]

```
private SendMessage sendToNoneSubscribers(Update update) throws TelegramApiException {
    var chatId = update.getMessage().getChatId();
    var fName = update.getMessage().getFrom().getFirstName();

    var channels = service.getAllChannels();

    var sendMessage = new SendMessage();

    var replyMarkup = new InlineKeyboardMarkup();

    List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>> keyboardsList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<InlineKeyboardButton> keyboards = new ArrayList<>();

    for (var channel : channels) {
      var getChatMember = new GetChatMember();
      getChatMember.setChatId("@examplechannel"); // I use also https://t.me
      getChatMember.setUserId(chatId);

      ChatMember chatMember = execute(getChatMember);// It cannot execute

      var isSubscriber = getChatMember.getUserId().equals(chatId);

      if (!isSubscriber) {
        var inlineKey = new InlineKeyboardButton();
        inlineKey.setText(channel.getChannelName());
        inlineKey.setUrl(channel.getUrl());
        keyboards.add(inlineKey);
        keyboardsList.add(keyboards);

        sendMessage.setText("Hi " + fName + ". You should join this channels");
      }
    }

    replyMarkup.setKeyboard(keyboardsList);

    sendMessage.setChatId(String.valueOf(chatId));
    sendMessage.setReplyMarkup(replyMarkup);

    return sendMessage;
  }
```